Как изменить строчку кода HTML на чужом сайте tampermonkey?
Знаю что вопрос глупый, но для решения моей проблемы мне очень нужно - очень прошу у Вас помощи, знаю что можно сделать это через tampermonkey, не знаю как(
Суть такая:
Есть код на сайте, у которого указан тип ввода "number"
Исходный код:
<input _ngcontent-ng-c733194650="" nz-input="" type="number" placeholder="Employee ID" class="ant-input ng-pristine ng-valid ant-input-stepperless ng-star-inserted ng-touched">

мне нужно чтобы он всегда был пустой
Изменённый код:
<input _ngcontent-ng-c733194650="" nz-input="" type="" placeholder="Employee ID" class="ant-input ng-pristine ng-valid ant-input-stepperless ng-star-inserted ng-touched">

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать
доступа к сайту нет, сайт не мой. Мне нужно чтобы эти изменения были только у меня...

Решение дали на сайте HABR. Автор: @byte916

Установите в браузер дополнение, которое делает js-иньекции в сайт. Например, в Firefox первое что нашлось - JS Injector.

Добавьте в этом приложении, для нужного сайта такой код:
document.querySelector('[placeholder="Employee ID"]').type='';



Написал как можно и на tampermonkey делать подобное.

В tampermonkey нужно нажать на кнопку создать скрипт:

Далее открывается окно создания скрипта:

// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      2024-05-02
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1578627/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-html-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-tampermonkey
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=stackoverflow.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const questionHeader = document.querySelector('h1 > a[class="question-hyperlink"]');

    if (questionHeader) {
        questionHeader.textContent = 'Данный заголовок заменил Tampermonkey';
    }
})();

В @match должна быть ссылка на ваш сайт, чтобы скрипт запускался автоматически когда вы вошли на нужный вам сайт.
В примере выше, я например меняю заголовок вашего текущего вопроса.
После сохранения скрипта и перезагрузки страницы я вижу следующее:

В вашем же случае скрипт будет выглядет как-то так:
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Employee ID input type changer
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      2024-05-02
// @description  Description
// @author       You
// @match        ВАША_ССЫЛКА_НА_САЙТ
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const employeeIdInput = document.querySelector('[placeholder="Employee ID"]');

    if (employeeIdInput) {
        employeeIdInput.type = '';
    }
})();


